# How can I claim my atmosphere packages?

Tags: meteor, migration, package, meteorite, atmosphere

Probably due to the automatic migration to Meteor 0.9.0 most (if not all) of my atmosphere packages got prefixed with `mrt:` username. I am wondering if there's some way to fix this, other than publishing the package again. I am asking because I observed that some other packages have proper "owner prefix" assigned and also the package maintainer is defined correctly.

Comment: You should definitely read these notes : https://hackpad.com/Migrating-Packages-zN0we9sIjkH, haven't tried this stuff myself though.

Comment: @saimeunt Of cource I have. They say nothing about the issue,

Comment: Here is the solution : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/kGVQ4wLch9c

Comment: @saimeunt Yes I know, thank you. I was one of "some people" to ask Tom about that issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove `mrt` as a contributor:

```
meteor admin maintainers <your_username>:<your_package> --remove mrt
```

If you were originally the maintainer on the old package system, you can attach your Meteor Developer account at http://atmosphere.meteor.com/accounts, then [ping @tmeasday](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/issues/55) to give you ownership of the old package.

Comment: Thanks Dan! This question was originally only about "adding myself as a contributor" so what you have written is a nice complement.